# What is a GCRecord in a database?

Tags: database, garbage-collection, ssms

I have been recently introduced to MVC, in which uses a SQL database.

In most of the tables within the project, there is a column for `OptimisticLockField`, and a `GCRecord` (both of type `int`).

I have found quite extensive info on the Optimistic/pessimistic locks. However, I can't find exactly what this GCRecord is used for, or when it is used, nor why it was included.

The only 'definition' is this one liner:

> A GC record represents a single garbage collection activity. It is
>   independent of whether the GC occured due to a manual GC request or an
>   allocation failure.

But am still none the wiser as to what this means, or even if it is the right 'definition' for this context.

Is this just a SQL thing? Or should this be used in most/all databases?

Comment: Are you talking about SQL Server - or some other SQL database product? - the [tag:sql] tag is for the language. For neither SQL Server nor the SQL language, so far as I'm aware, is GCRecord the name of something built in - so it's more likely that its a term specific to the project.

Comment: i'm using SSMS but I honestly don't know if it's built in or not? Will remove that tag though as it *could* be misleading for this topic.

Answer (score 1):

The GCRecord field is used to mark objects which have been removed from the collection. It is part of a mechanism called [deferred deletion](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/CustomDocument2103)